# Inserting into multiple tables

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am using Delphi2010 and I'm trying to do an insert into multiple tables. I don't know the best way to do this. What I'm wondering is if there is a possible way to do one insert using one of Delphi's tools like the TQuery or TClientDataSet or would it be better to use code (we use Pascal language). An array maybe? I haven't been using Delphi that long but I have inserted and updated info into one table before, not multiple. Also, these tables use pretty much the same field names.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: You are, by far, not providing enough information to give any meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Call a stored procedure to update your tables simultaneously, with a transaction wrapper.  Or re-design your database to eliminate duplicate/redundant data, so that you would never need to update several tables at once.
Note that this answer is perfectly valid, given the information provided in the question...
(Note: it's late, couldn't sleep, bored. This is what you get, given the quality of the information in the question!)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution could be to make a updateable view on the database, and update the view from Delphi.
Making a updateable view just moves the work of updating 2 tables to the SQL instead of in Delphi.
This moves the business logic to the sql instead of in the Delphi. It propobly also generates less network trafic.

As Chris writes: use transactions, when 2 or more updates/inserts is dependent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Which data access componentes do you use ?
Which restrictions do you have ? 
do you want to insert the same values into both tables ?
why not easy like:

```
 for i = low(tables) to high(tables) do
  begin
    query.sql.text := 'insert into '+tables[i]+' (fields) values('+ ...)';
    query.execsql;
  end;
```